# \fullcite not working as it should

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm trying to make the code of the following post work: [How to make a bib entry appear also in the main document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44394/how-to-make-a-bib-entry-appear-also-in-the-main-document/44445#44445) but I get some thing that I don't expect:

[image]

I'm using the default TeXShop command: `pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1`.
I also tried to run `bibtex`, but I get the following message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

**EDIT**

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{auth1:2000,
title = {A book},
author = {A. Thor},
date = {2000},
publisher = {Some Company},
location = {A City}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{auth1:2000}
\cite{auth1:2000}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which is clearly wrong as I'm citing in the test. What's wrong?

Comment: The same problem is also discussed here [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135930/use-bibentry-with-biblatex] and here [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126226/how-do-i-instruct-fullcite-to-use-maxbibnames-rather-than-maxcitenames]. Note that the answer provided there is actually more accurate than the one provided here (so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the backend `biber` you need to run `biber` instead of `bibtex`. Your code is working fine for me when I run `pdflatex`, then `biber`, and then `pdflatex` again:

[image: Output]

If I don't run `biber` after `pdflatex` I get the same output as you.

Just in case `biber` was not set up: [This guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/62746) is incredibly helpful (includes guides for many editors, among which also TexShop).

Answer (score 3):

As written in the comments the default backend of `biblatex`2 and higher is `biber`. To use the traditional backend `bibtex` you have to specify this as an option:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```