# How do I instruct \fullcite to use maxbibnames rather than maxcitenames?

Tags: biblatex, citing, author-number

For my PhD thesis, I am including a *List of appended papers* automagically.  To generate the references, I used to use `\bibentry`, but now I switched to biblatex and headed for `\fullcite` hoping it to be an equivalent.  Alas, `\fullcite` uses `maxcitenames` to decide the number of authors; I'd like it to use `maxbibnames` so that the number of authors printed is like it is in the bibliogaphy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
This is by \textcite{A01}, or, more completely:
\fullcite{A01}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The desired effect:

`This is by Author et al. [1], or, more completely, A. Author, B. Buthor, C. Cuthor, and D. Duthor, Alpha, 2001`

The actual effect:

[image: resulting document]

How do I get a full citation with all authors (or `maxbibnames` no. of authors) with `\fullcite` or a similar command in `biblatex`?  If I change `maxcitenames`, then `Author et al. [1]` will also be affected, and this is not desired.

All my `\fullcite` occurences are concentrated in one part of the document that uses no other citation commands, so a solution temporarily changing `maxcitenames` would be acceptable for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may change the definition of the `\fullcite` and `\footfullcite` cite macros so that they locally use the value of `maxbibnames`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
This is by \textcite{A01}, or, more completely:
\fullcite{A01}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!  That was more difficult than I had expected.

Comment: See also Kevin's answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101744/28346).

Answer (score 36):

Either make a new command:

```
\newcommand{\printpublication}[1]{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}\fullcite{#1}}
```

Or modify `\fullcite` globally:

```
\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\preto\fullcite{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}

\begin{document}
This is by \textcite{A01}, or, more completely:
\fullcite{A01}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is also how to do this by resetting `\blx@maxcitenames` locally. Using tracing, one can see that:

```
...
\blx@resetdata ->\let \blx@saved@do \do \let \do \blx@imc@clearname \abx@doname
s \let \do \blx@imc@clearlist \abx@dolists \let \do \blx@imc@clearfield \abx@do
fields \do {options}\do {labeltitle}\do {labelyear}\do {labelmonth}\do {labelda
y}\do {datelabelsource}\abx@dointernalfields \def \do ##1{\togglefalse {abx@boo
l@##1}}\abx@dobooleans \let \do \blx@saved@do \c@citecounter \z@ \iftoggle {blx
@bibliography} {\c@maxnames \blx@maxbibnames \relax \c@minnames \blx@minbibname
s \relax } {\c@maxnames \blx@maxcitenames \relax \c@minnames \blx@mincitenames 
\relax }\c@maxitems \blx@maxitems \relax \c@minitems \blx@minitems \relax
```

So, one could either temporarily set the toggle `blx@bibliography` to true (in local scope): that would end up using `\blx@maxbibnames` -- or, one could temporarily (in local scope) set the "counter" `\blx@maxcitenames` to say 99; note `\blx@maxcitenames` is not an actual `\newcount` or `\newcounter`, it is a "mere" command.

Below the example temporarily/locally sets the `\blx@maxcitenames` to 99, the typeouts should confirm that that change does not influence global scope; output is the same as in accepted answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{trace}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


This is by \textcite{A01}, or, more completely:
\makeatletter%
\typeout{blx@maxcitenames: \blx@maxcitenames}%
\bgroup% start local scope group
  % \advance\blx@maxcitenames 2\relax % cannot: not a count!
  \def\blx@maxcitenames{99}%
  \makeatother%
  % \traceon % if tracing is desired
  \fullcite{A01}.
  % \traceoff
\egroup%

\makeatletter
\typeout{blx@maxcitenames: \blx@maxcitenames}
\makeatother

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```