# biblatex: \citeauthor should show more names than \textcite (no "et al.")

Tags: biblatex

- I am using `\citeauthor` from the package `biblatex` to print the author names of a publication.
- I want that `\citeauthor` prints ALL names (only be limited by `maxbibnames` and not by `maxcitenames`.
- Is there a clean way to do that?
- I am *flexible* regarding the details (e. g. incl. or excluding the given names).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[maxcitenames = 2, maxbibnames = 10]{biblatex}

% See https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[cite] \textcite{padhye}
\item[citeauthor] \citeauthor{padhye}: Here, I need the full list (up to 'maxbibnames = 10') of authors as shown in the bibliography.
\end{description}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is the same as in [How do I instruct \fullcite to use maxbibnames rather than maxcitenames?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126226/35864). Take the original definition of `\citeauthor` ([ll. 2172-2181 in `biblatex.def` v3.17](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/64156e27b9501bab86cab5ed9ee58e8a6a5ce67f/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2172-L2181)) and add a `\defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}` to locally set the `maxnames` counter to its bibliography value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[maxcitenames = 2, maxbibnames = 10]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}%
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[cite] \textcite{padhye}
\item[citeauthor] \citeauthor{padhye}
\item[cite] \textcite{padhye}
\end{description}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image: cite Padhye et al. [1] citeauthor Padhye, Firoiu, and Towsley cite Padhye et al. [1] Jitendra Padhye, Victor Firoiu, and Don Towsley.]