# How to input bibliography right after text using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biber

I heard that it's possible to do this with natbib but I am using biblatex with biber backend but I already have my bib file ready. Is there any way to do this with biblatex?[image]

Pic related red underline is how I want it to work.

Comment: Something like `\fullcite`? If this does not help, please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: It seems this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135930/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44394/35864 Is `\fullcite` really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve something similar with a verbose biblatex style. In your preamble, add

```
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
```

or, if you want your bibliography to stay the way it looks now (however that is), use

```
\usepackage[%
    citestyle=verbose,
    bibstyle=examplestyle
]{biblatex}
```

where `examplestyle` is replaced by the style of your choice.

Thanks to moewe for the corrections in the comments.

Comment: It should be `citestyle=verbose` without the dash. `citestyle=verbose, style=authoryear` would just be `style=authoryear` since `style` sets both `citestyle` and `bibstyle`. Since `verbose` uses an `authoryear` layout of the bibliography, `(bib)style=authoryear` makes little sense combined with `verbose`.

Comment: Right. The authoryear was just an example, albeit a bad one, since it doesn't change anything in this case. I will do the necessary corrections. Thx for the input.